# Rails ActionMailer without views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 4.2 and I have some mailers that I don't want to use a view for. I have another method that is rendering the html. If I want to skip the views and pass the rendered html from this method. How can I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of different ways avoid using a template/view for a mailer.

The first is to pass `body` to `mail`:

```
mail(to: 'kyledecot@example.com', body: 'Welcome')
```

The second way is to pass a block to `mail`

```
mail(to: 'kyledecot@example.com') do |format|
  format.text { render plain: "Welcome" }
  format.html { render html: "<h1>Welcome</h1>".html_safe }
end
```

If you're curious here's the relevant file:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb#L876

Comment: I don't have to do anything to tell ActionMailer not to look for a view?

Comment: You have to supply *some* kind of body to `mail`. Doing this tells ActionMailer to not looks for a template